# Is there risk of bricking in attempting to install a custom recovery on adevice that has been compromised and has sstem level malware apps on it?

Tags: recovery-mode, unbricking, malware

My phone has been compromised and has malware system apps that have persisted after factory reset. I'd like to install a custom recovery so that I can at least get it back to functional if I brick it while rooting and trying to clean house.

But I worry that the bad actor will have altered things enough that if I try to set up a custom recovery to take a system image, it will end up irrecoverably bricked - are there cases of installing custom recovery bricking a phone for good, with and without known malware on the device?

Comment: If you are making system modifications there is always a risk to brick the system. Depending on the device and what you do the risk can be serous to negligible. Hence the only answer I can give to you is `yes there is a risk`. But anyway on a compromised device it really does not matter if you recycle the device directly or accidentally brick it while trying to restore it.

Comment: for removal of malware you can install official ROM with official flash tool, no need for custom recovery

Comment: @alecxs Not valid when the stock ROM itself contains malware.

Comment: @Grimoire true, thx for complement. guess in this case it's most likely xhelper malware which uses mtk-su